# SonarQube: How to fail build if sonarqube quality code code coverage in PR is less then current coverage in master?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

For Instance: The code coverage of my project is 80% in master branch. I created new feature branch from master and did my changes. Now, the coverage from this feature branch is 75% . I want to fail my build if it goes less than the current coverage.

Please let me know if it's possible with Sonarqube and I'm using SonarQube 8.9.3 Version.